# how to toggle a icon based on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Have 3  Toggle Icons [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QFjz.png)

I want to change the icon to toggle on when its clicked like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA46f.png)

I wrote a jquery for that but it only works for 1st icon .

```js
function settingsClicked() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#settings-btn').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("fa-toggle-off fa-toggle-on");
    });
  });
}
```

```css
settings {
  padding: 10px;
}

.settings p {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #1e698d;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.settings i {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.fa-toggle-on {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dashboard">
  <form>
    <fieldset class="dashboard-border">
      <legend class="legend-border">Settings</legend>
      <div class="settings">
        <p>Settings 1 : </p> <i class="fas fa-toggle-off" id="settings-btn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="settings">
        <p>Settings 2 : </p> <i class="fas fa-toggle-off" id="settings-btn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="settings">
        <p>Settings 3 : </p> <i class="fas fa-toggle-off" id="settings-btn"></i>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It's invalid to have multiple elements with same id in a html-document.

Comment: what do u suggest me to do.

Comment: use a class selector instead of id selector

Comment: Use css-classes instead and use that as a selector in jQuery/javascript.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/0c6yongr/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you cannot use the same `id` for multiple elements. So first off, remove those duplicate ids.

You could try using an alternative selector instead, based on your HTML then the following should work:

```
    $('div.settings i').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("fa-toggle-off fa-toggle-on");
    });
```

This will select the `i` elements found within any `div` that has `class="settings"`.

Comment: @AnamolShrestha: No problem, just be sure to take away the knowledge that you should not use duplicate ids!

Answer (score 1):

Its only working for the first button because you are replicating the id - each id needs to be unique. I have simply appended a number to the end of the id to ensure the id is unique. Note that you will need to alter the selector for the click handler - and sincethere are multiple elements - better to use a class.

```
 <div class="dashboard">
        <form>
            <fieldset class="dashboard-border">
                <legend class="legend-border">Settings</legend>
                <div class="settings">
                    <p>Settings 1 : </p> <i class="fas fa-toggle-off" id="settings-btn1"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="settings">
                    <p>Settings 2 : </p> <i class="fas fa-toggle-off" id="settings-btn2"></i>           
                </div>
                <div class="settings">
                    <p>Settings 3 : </p> <i class="fas fa-toggle-off" id="settings-btn3"></i>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>    
    </div>
```

Comment: its not working even i set unique ids , not even for first one . suggest me a jquery edit also

Answer (score 0):

You can only use an `id` one time.

If you want to toggle it for every button you could do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.settings-btn').click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("fa-toggle-off fa-toggle-on");
            });
    });
```

```css
settings {
  padding: 10px;
}

.settings p {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #1e698d;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.settings i {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.fa-toggle-on {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dashboard">
  <form>
    <fieldset class="dashboard-border">
      <legend class="legend-border">Settings</legend>
      <div class="settings">
        <p>Settings 1 : </p> <i class="fas fa-toggle-off settings-btn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="settings">
        <p>Settings 2 : </p> <i class="fas fa-toggle-off settings-btn"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="settings">
        <p>Settings 3 : </p> <i class="fas fa-toggle-off settings-btn"></i>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

It is not valid way to having multiple Tags with same id.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('div.settings i').click(function () {
         $(this).toggleClass("fa-toggle-off fa-toggle-on");
    });
      });
```

```css
    settings {
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .settings p {
      display: inline;
      font-size: 22px;
      color: #1e698d;
      font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .settings i {
      font-size: 30px;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .fa-toggle-on {
      color: green;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="dashboard">
      <form>
        <fieldset class="dashboard-border">
          <legend class="legend-border">Settings</legend>
          <div class="settings">
            <p>Settings 1 : </p> <i class="fas fa-toggle-off" id="settings-btn"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="settings">
            <p>Settings 2 : </p> <i class="fas fa-toggle-off" id="settings-btn"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="settings">
            <p>Settings 3 : </p> <i class="fas fa-toggle-off" id="settings-btn"></i>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
```